# Escape string special characters for use in golang regexp

Tags: regex, string, go

I have an array of characters like this :

```
chars := []string{".", "-", "(", ")"}
```

When I join them in regular way (`strings.Join(chars, "")`) and pass it to `regexp.MustCompile`, Its panic :

```
panic: regexp: Compile(`[.-()]`): error parsing regexp: invalid character class range: `.-(`
```

How can I scape string special characters for use in golang regexp as a character not regexp operator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must put the `-` item at the start/end of the array so that `-` appears either at the start - `[-.()]` -  or end - `[.()-]` - of the character class.

Or escape the `-` in the `chars` array: `"\\-"`.

**NOTE**: That is not the only caveat, the `^` and `]` must also be escaped, or placed in a specific location in the character class.  The `\` must be escaped always.

See a [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/7ZBKa3m6yx):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    chars := []string{"]", "^", "\\\\", "[", ".", "(", ")", "-"}
    r := strings.Join(chars, "")
    s := "[Some]-\\(string)^."
    re := regexp.MustCompile("[" + r + "]+")
    s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output: `Somestring`

Note that the `^` must not be the first item, `]` must be at the start and `-` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is an even better way:

```
regexp.MustCompile( regexp.QuoteMeta(strings.Join(chars, "")) )
```

`regexp.QuoteMeta()` will create a regular expression that matches the string provided exactly (i.e. it will escape all the regex meta-characters).